# Why do review tasks come in groups?

Tags: support, review

I don't have much reputation on Stack Overflow, so I may only review first Questions & Answers. When waiting for a review task, I realized that there are no tasks at all (some minutes) and then there suddently are 8 or 13 tasks to do. Why does it behave like this? Wouldn't it be more logical that a review task is created when a new user posts a new question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching.  Always caching.  30char.

Comment: You could answer in a complete sentence to get to 30 char.